# Tell us about "clientToWorld"

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

"clientToWorld" is used to identify and mark members and coordinates.
We are also considering implementing a function to display attribute information of the selected members.
However, the dbid of the member specified by "clientToWorld" is the Leaf Object's one, and the correct attribute information cannot be obtained.

When selecting a member by simply clicking the mouse, Leaf or First is selected by "SelectionMode". Isn't the same control possible with "clientToWorld"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try find the node id per the desired selection mode after getting the dbid from `clientToWorld`:

```
const result = NOP_VIEWER.clientToWorld(x,y);
NOP_VIEWER.model.getInstanceTree().findNodeForSelection(result.dbId,Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionMode["LEAF_OBJECT"])
```